# Find 2nd Largest value after N - Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the 2nd largest value after N, in this case 33 in a list of numbers which here would be 29.

Here is the formula I've been experimenting with for the past 45 minutes with various tweaks/versions but have not had any luck.  I think it has to be a mix of `MAX` and `LARGE`

`=MAXIFS(A5:A14,A5:A14,C8,A5:A14,LARGE(A5:A14,2))` (CTRL SHIFT ENTER) which results in just zero.

I think I'm close but not quite there.

[image: 2nd_largest_Value]

Comment: `=MAXIFS(A5:A14,A5:A14,"<"&C8)`

Comment: Ha!  I guess I was tremendously over thinking it.  Thank you Scott !